# Is there a cupertino equivelent of SwitchListTile?

Tags: flutter

I need to create a settings page for my iOS app. On my Android side, I have SwitchListTile to layout the switches nicely.

Is there a Flutter widget that would help me or do I have to write one myself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to write one yourself, however, you can crib from the SwitchListTile source pretty easily:

````
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() => runApp(new MyApp());
    
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() => MyAppState();
    }
    
    class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      bool _isSelected = false;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          home: new SafeArea(
              child: new Material(
                  child: new ListView(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new CupertinoSwitchListTile(
                        value: _isSelected,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          print("Value changed to $value");
                          setState(() => _isSelected = value);
                        },
                        activeColor: CupertinoColors.activeGreen
                      )
                    ],
                  ))),
        );
      }
    
    }
    class CupertinoSwitchListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  /// This has been shamelessly copied from Material/SwitchListTile.
  /// The applicable license applies.
  const CupertinoSwitchListTile({
    Key? key,
    required this.value,
    required this.onChanged,
    this.activeColor,
    this.title,
    this.subtitle,
    this.isThreeLine = false,
    this.dense,
    this.secondary,
    this.selected = false,
  })  : assert(value != null),
        assert(isThreeLine != null),
        assert(!isThreeLine || subtitle != null),
        assert(selected != null),
        super(key: key);

  /// Whether this switch is checked.
  ///
  /// This property must not be null.
  final bool value;

  /// Called when the user toggles the switch on or off.
  ///
  /// The switch passes the new value to the callback but does not actually
  /// Change state until the parent widget rebuilds the switch tile with the
  /// new value.
  ///
  /// If null, the switch will be displayed as disabled.
  ///
  /// The callback provided to [onChanged] should update the state of the parent
  /// [StatefulWidget] using the [State.setState] method, so that the parent
  /// gets rebuilt; for example:
  ///
  /// ```dart
  /// new SwitchListTile(
  ///   value: _lights,
  ///   onChanged: (bool newValue) {
  ///     setState(() {
  ///       _lights = newValue;
  ///     });
  ///   },
  ///   title: new Text('Lights'),
  /// )
  /// ```
  final ValueChanged<bool>? onChanged;

  /// The color to use when this switch is on.
  ///
  /// Defaults to accent color of the current [Theme].
  final Color? activeColor;

  /// The primary content of the list tile.
  ///
  /// Typically a [Text] widget.
  final Widget? title;

  /// Additional content displayed below the title.
  ///
  /// Typically a [Text] widget.
  final Widget? subtitle;

  /// A widget to display on the opposite side of the tile from the switch.
  ///
  /// Typically an [Icon] widget.
  final Widget? secondary;

  /// Whether this list tile is intended to display three lines of text.
  ///
  /// If false, the list tile is treated as having one line if the subtitle is
  /// null and treated as having two lines if the subtitle is non-null.
  final bool isThreeLine;

  /// Whether this list tile is part of a vertically dense list.
  ///
  /// If this property is null then its value is based on [ListTileTheme.dense].
  final bool? dense;

  /// Whether to render icons and text in the [activeColor].
  ///
  /// No effort is made to automatically coordinate the [selected] state and the
  /// [value] state. To have the list tile appear selected when the switch is
  /// on, pass the same value to both.
  ///
  /// Normally, this property is left to its default value, false.
  final bool selected;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var color = activeColor ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary;
    print("Active color: ${color.red} ${color.green} ${color.blue}");
    final Widget control = CupertinoSwitch(
      value: value,
      onChanged: onChanged,
      activeColor: activeColor ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
    );
    return MergeSemantics(
      child: ListTileTheme.merge(
        selectedColor: activeColor ?? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary,
        child: ListTile(
          leading: secondary,
          title: title,
          subtitle: subtitle,
          trailing: control,
          isThreeLine: isThreeLine,
          dense: dense,
          enabled: onChanged != null,
          onTap: onChanged != null
              ? () {
                  onChanged!(!value);
                }
              : null,
          selected: selected,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
````

As I noted in the source, because it's copied from the flutter source the [license at time of copying](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/19ef85bf6c8604a02f9543b02fa5218a3c13784d/LICENSE) from the source applies.

Answer (score 7):

Use **SwitchListTile.adaptive** widget instead of **SwitchListTile** widget

Comment: It's really that easy, huh? Thx a million!

Answer (score 2):

Since Flutter 2, there are now Cupertino equivalents of the [SwitchListTile](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SwitchListTile-class.html).

You can use a combination of [CupertinoFormSection](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoFormSection-class.html), [CupertinoFormRow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoFormRow-class.html), [CupertinoSwitch](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/cupertino/CupertinoSwitch-class.html) widgets to produce validated form fields with iOS’s sectioned visual aesthetics.

```dart
CupertinoFormSection(
  header: Text('Section 1'),
  children: <Widget>[
    CupertinoFormRow(
      child: CupertinoSwitch(
        value: toggleValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            toggleValue = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      prefix: Text('Toggle 1'),
      helper: Text('Slide me'),
      error: toggleValue ? null : Text('Not slided'),
    ),
    CupertinoFormRow(
      child: CupertinoSwitch(
        value: !toggleValue,
        onChanged: (value) {
          setState(() {
            toggleValue = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      prefix: Text('Toggle 2'),
    ),
  ],
)
```

[image: Cupertino form with Switch]

Answer (score 2):

Just Change the SwitchListTile to ListTile remove the fields "value" and "onchanged" and set a CupertinoSwitch as a trailing parameter. like this

From:

```
return SwitchListTile(
    title: Text(title),
    subtitle: Text(subTitle),
    value: value,
    onChanged: onChanged);
```

To:

```
return ListTile(
  title: Text(title),
  subtitle: Text(subTitle),
  trailing: CupertinoSwitch(value: value, onChanged: onChanged),
);
```

hope that it helped.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not replicate full functionality of a SwitchListTile: switch value does not change when you tap on the tile itself, only when you tap on the switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CupertivoSwitch inside a ListTile

Example:

```
class _HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  bool isDarkMode = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: const Text('Dark Mode'),
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  isDarkMode = !isDarkMode;
                });
              },
              leading: const Icon(Icons.dark_mode),
              trailing:
                  CupertinoSwitch(value: isDarkMode, onChanged: (value) {}),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Result:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just like @Badi3 said, use the following code:

```
SwitchListTile.adaptive(
      value: value,
      onChanged: (foobar) {
        setState(() {
          // todo
        });
      },
      title: Text(
        "Foo",
        style: TextStyle(),
      ),
      subtitle: Text(
        "Bar bar bar",
        style: TextStyle(),
      ),
      activeColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
    ),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Make a custom component like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class CupertinoSwitchListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const CupertinoSwitchListTile({
    Key key,
    @required this.onChanged,
    @required this.value,
    @required this.text,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Function onChanged;
  final bool value;
  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      onTap: onChanged,
      title: Text(text),
      leading: CupertinoSwitch(
        value: value,
        onChanged: (bool isChecked) => onChanged(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use it like this after declare a bool variable called a boolValue in a statefullWidget:

```
CupertinoSwitchListTile(
                    onChanged: () {
                      setState(() {
                          boolValue = !boolValue;
                      });
                    },
                    text: 'toggle switch',
                    value: boolValue,
                  )
```

[image]